# using todoist python api to add a recurring task

Tags: python, todoist

I am trying to add a recurring task to todoist using the python api.

- Official API Doc: https://developer.todoist.com/sync/v7/#add-two-new-tasks
- Official Python library: https://github.com/Doist/todoist-python
- Other Python library: https://github.com/Garee/pytodoist
- Other Python library doc: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pytodoist/latest/pytodoist.pdf

I tried this below but don't know how to specify the recurring settings

```
from pytodoist import todoist
user = todoist.login('login', 'pass')
project = user.get_project('my_project')
task = project.add_task('My Recuring task')
task = project.add_task('My Recuring task tomorrow at 2 pm')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use our main library.

Here is a one-liner that creates a new task for every day:

```
python2.7 -c "import todoist; import os; token = os.environ.get('token'); api = todoist.TodoistAPI(token); api.items.add('test', None, date_string='ev day'); api.commit()"
```

Breaking it down:

```
# import the library
import todoist

# retrieve the token from my environment variables
import os
token = os.environ.get('token'); 

# initialize the API object
api = todoist.TodoistAPI(token)

# Create a new task called "test", with "None" as the project id and date_string as kwargs for the arguments of the item.
api.items.add('test', None, date_string='ev day')

# commit it! :)
api.commit()"
```

In the last argument you can pass all arguments [available in the documentation as command arguments](https://developer.todoist.com/sync/v7/#add-an-item)